# Signing error when building an app bundle with 2048 bit key

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, keytool

I have a script which, among other things, calls `keytool` to generate a signing key for my apps as I create them. It appears that in the recent past, some system update has led to me getting a version of `keytool` (or underlying libraries) which, when creating a key pair, defaults to creating (I assume) a 2048 bit key rather than the old default of 1024 bits.

For my latest project, I created a keypair, signed an APK and uploaded it to Google Play. Now I am attempting to create a Bundle instead, but get the following error:

```
The security strength of SHA-1 digest algorithm is not sufficient for this key size
```

Some other questions report this error as a side-effect of problems with the bundle format (broken images, etc), but I have verified by generating a new key that's explicitly 1024 bits that it is a problem with the key itself. Generating such a key with `keytool` emits the following warning:

> The generated certificate uses a 1024-bit DSA key which is considered a security risk. This key size will be disabled in a future update.

1. Given that Google Play has seen this upload key for internal test versions of the app, is there something I can do to the `signBundle` phase of the build that will get it to work correctly for this app, or do I need to request a new upload key?
2. Given that `keytool` has deprecated 1024-bit DSA keys, is there a set of parameters I can pass to it which will generate a key that will work correctly in future?

Comment: According to: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8u151-relnotes.html "For DSA keys, the default signature algorithm for keytool and jarsigner has changed from SHA1withDSA to SHA256withDSA and the default key size for keytool has changed from 1024 bits to 2048 bits.

Users wishing to revert to the previous behavior can use the -sigalg option of keytool and jarsigner and specify SHA1withDSA and the -keysize option of keytool and specify 1024."

So I guess this means that the jarsigner from AS is older than the keytool on my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the instructions at
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/key, I ended up generating a new 2048 bit RSA key, and requesting that Google replace the existing key with that.

`keytool -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 ...`